# Django Templates Iterate & render items in the list returned by a function

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

How to render the items in the list dd = [] returned from the function get_image in the template? the list contains list of files returned by the function.

Just wud like to add the index.html is under project_folder/inc/html where the images is under project_folder/inc/img & settings, views & url is in project_folder

**index.html**

```
<ul>
{% for object in dd %}
<li><img src="views.img_dir{{% views.img_dir.object.get_absolute_url %}}"></li>
<li><img src="views.img_dir{{% views.img_dir.dd.get_absolute_url %}}"></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

if I try this:

```
<ul>
{% for object in dd %}
<li><img src="{{settings.img_dir }}object.get_absolute_url"></li>
<li><img src="{{settings.img_dir }}{{%object%}}"></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I get a TemplateSyntaxError *Could not parse the remainder: '%object%' from '%object%'*

**views.py**

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
img_dir = os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, "inc/img/")

def get_image(request):
    for file in os.listdir(img_dir):
        h = []
        h.append(file)
        for l in h:
            r = l.endswith('.jpg') or l.endswith('.png') or l.endswith('.gif')
            if r == True:
                dd = []
                dd.append(l)
                return render_to_response('index.html', dd)
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', get_image),
```

**settings.py**

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "inc/html"),
)
```

Comment: hmm, tried the index.html loads but the images are not rendered :( any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did changed my templating from django to Jinja2: & with a littel change in my function I was able to render all the images on the template.

JINJA2 Template

Here's the function:

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
img_dir = os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, "inc/img")

class ImageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        images = os.listdir(img_dir)
        template = jinja.get_template('image.html')
        template_values = {'images': images}
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

the HTML:

```
<ul>
{% for img in images %}

    <li><img src="/img/{{ img|e  }}"></li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I did also get a snippet to render all images in Django but I change my templating system.

If anyone need to get it on Django here's the snippet:

VIEWS.PY

```
def index(request):
    """Renders the index for the site."""
    images = os.listdir(templates)
    images.sort()
    for i in xrange(len(images)):
        name = name_for_image(images[i])
        images[i] = (name, images[i])
    return shortcuts.render_to_response('index.html',
                                        {'images': images,},
                                        template.RequestContext(request))
```

index.html

```
{% for name, image in images %}
<td>
  <a href="{% url caption fn=image %}">
    <img src="{% url thumbnail fn=image %}"/><br/>{{ name }}
  </a>
</td>
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:5 %}</tr><tr>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

NOTE:The above code for Django needs some tweaking, as it also relies on another function named `def name_for_image(image):` which renders names of the images with the img src.

Answer (score 1):

Your template syntax is wrong.

You can't use `{{ %variable% }}`, it's either `{{ variable }}` or `{% function %}`

```
<li><img src="{{settings.img_dir }}{{%object%}}"></li>
```

should be

```
<li><img src="{{settings.img_dir }}{{ object }}"></li>
```

Also your first block that you supplied has multiple errors

```
{% for object in dd %}
    <li><img src="views.img_dir{{% views.img_dir.object.get_absolute_url %}}"></li>
    <li><img src="views.img_dir{{% views.img_dir.dd.get_absolute_url %}}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

1. `{{% varible %}}`
2. What is `views.img_dir`? You've defined it in your
   `views.py` I assume, but it never gets passed to the template. Therefor you won't be able to do `views.img_dir`. (Unless you've done some super magic you're not showing us)
3. Which leads to `views.img_dir.object` not being able to render.
4. And lastly, `views.img_dir.object` will never work since (assuming you've passed the object to the template) because it's a string and a string never has the property `object` form your for loop.

So as you can see, you have multiple errors in your code and you'll never get to render the images with that.

Comment: tried, the index.html loads but the images are not rendered on the page.

Comment: so how can I render them? as the list does gets the file list from the directory, I'm trying to render all images in the template through a function.

Comment: Have you followed the tutorial on how to render images in Django, because, given what you've done so far it seems as if it would benefit you the most

Comment: I did checked some links & google, but most of them returned confiruring the media & static_files directory in setting.py... & what I'm trying is to render it by a function, I just can't understand why its failing

Comment: The point being that you need to understand what the notion of a Static file is and how to serve it with Django. Django has a set way of serving it and you can't server files from an arbitrary catalog just willy nilly. I would suggest you add the catalog of images you want to render into your static files dir and then render it like this `{{ STATIC_FILES}}/img/my_image.jpg`

Comment: ok, so if I place the images in {{ STATIC_FILES}} then how do I show the images? wud it be `<li><img src="{{ STATIC_FILES}}{{ object }}"></li>`